# How to remove empty iframes with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

I'm using this code for removing empty iframes but I dont't know where I'm failing:

```
<body>
<section class="fu-banner-ad-list">
     <div class="fu-wfb-wrapper">
       <div class="mdl-cell mdl-cell--2-col ">
          <div class="adunit fu-banner-wfb " data-adunit="XXX_YYY42 " data-dimensions="150x50 ">
            &nbsp;
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    ....more iframes
</section>
   <script type="text/javascript">
        if ($('.mdl-cell--2-col').is(':empty')) { 
            $('.mdl-cell--2-col').remove();
        } 

    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Where are the `<iframes />`? You have divs. And Those divs have a child element and that means it is not empty.

Comment: .is(':empty') would check if the inner html is empty or not. Since in your case you already have a child div, it would never execute the next block.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try $('.mdl-cell--2-col').empty()?

more info [here](https://api.jquery.com/empty/)

Comment: that doesn't matter. his selector is looking for inner html to be empty which is not. so it would never run remove() func. $('.mdl-cell--2-col').empty() would remove all underlying html